# Split text file in to array using regular expression PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-split

I have some changelog text in a string and I would like to split each changelog entry into an array.

Here's an example of the changelog text in a variable - `$changelog_txt`:

```
version 4.4.6 ( updated 05-08-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.

version 4.4.5 ( updated 05-01-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.
```

So, the resulting output would be an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    [0] => version 4.4.6 ( updated 05-08-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.
    [1] => version 4.4.5 ( updated 05-01-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.
)
```

Can anyone help or offer any suggestions?

Comment: preg_split();  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: @AdamWinter yes, I've seen that already but I'm struggling with the actual regular expression required for this... I was hoping for some guidance on the actual regular expression needed.

Comment: @Mat, I've added answer for you with `preg_split()`

Comment: What is the logic you want to split on? An empty line or should the structure of the listed be taken into account with the version and the hyphens? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to make an array.

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
version 4.4.6 ( updated 05-08-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.

version 4.4.5 ( updated 05-01-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.
EOD;
$keywords = array_map('trim',preg_split("/^\s*$/m", $str));
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/1mpZH

**Regex Explanation:**

```
/^\s*$/m
```

`^` asserts position at start of a line

`\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

`*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`$` asserts position at the end of a line
Global pattern flags

`m` modifier: multi line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: Thanks, this works on my sample data perfectly. However, would you mind explaining the regular expression and what it actually does, both for me and others reading this?

Comment: @Mat any specific reason for un-accepting  my answer? is there any issue with the solution?

Comment: This only works if you have a blank line in between each element.  What would you do if you didn't?

Answer (score 0):

You could preg_replace_callback() to insert your own delimiter, then explode().

```
<?php
$oldString ='version 4.4.6 ( updated 05-08-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.

version 4.4.5 ( updated 05-01-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.';

$newString = preg_replace_callback('(version [0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]?)', function($matches){return 'myUnlikelyDelimiter'.$matches[0];}, $oldString);

$array = explode('myUnlikelyDelimiter', $newString);

var_dump($array);
?>
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about doing it this way to be honest and I like the thinking behind it!

Comment: [0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9]? matches singledigit.singledigit.single/doubledigit

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input_lines = <<<EOD
version 4.4.6 ( updated 05-08-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD         actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.

version 4.4.5 ( updated 05-01-2020 )
- Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD  actions in Layers panel.
- Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
- Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
- Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.
EOD;
preg_match_all('/(^[\s\S]*(?:\r*\n{2}))/U', $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => version 4.4.6 ( updated 05-08-2020 )
                - Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for  Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
                - Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
                - Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
                - Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => version 4.4.6 ( updated 05-08-2020 )
                - Improved logic to keep collapse/expand state consistent for Add/Clone/Delete/DnD actions in Layers panel.
                - Updated Layers panel to allow selecting Goal and Winner for Split Testing from Layers panel.
                - Improved the Visual Builder scroll performance.
                - Added vmin and vmax to css allowed units in module settings.


        )

)
```